# Archiving react-native project fails with `_RCTCxxBridge` error

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10.2

I tried a number of solutions I found on the web without any luck. I want to archive a react-native project but it keeps failing with this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTCxxBridge", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTBridge.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my `podfile`

```
rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'BatchedBridge',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'Core',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]

  # 'Core',
  # 'CxxBridge',
  # 'BatchedBridge',
  # 'DevSupport',
  # 'RCTActionSheet',
  # 'RCTAnimation',
  # 'RCTGeolocation',
  # 'RCTImage',
  # 'RCTLinkingIOS',
  # 'RCTNetwork',
  # 'RCTSettings',
  # 'RCTText',
  # 'RCTVibration',
  # 'RCTWebSocket',
```

The commented libraries were the one I tried to use at first and on searching I commented it and replaced it with the one that are there.

Here is the link binary with libraries list:

[image]

**react-native version : 0.58.1**

**xcode version : 10.2**

Comment: create an empty project ... link npm modules that require linking like `react-native-sound` **<one-by-one>** and run-ios after each step to make sure everything is linked correctly

Comment: Have you seen this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15838#issuecomment-333455341?

Comment: @user3764429 tried it .. didn't work